# How to check AWS CLI Installed in Windows machine

Tags: wix, aws-cli

I am working on Wix Installer Burn Setup Project.
AWS CLI is one of the Prerequisite software.
My issue is if AWS CLI is already installed need to avoid Repair or Uninstall screens on the WIX burn setup.

How to check whether AWS CLI installed in Machine or not TO specify the Install Condtion in Wix Burn Setup.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at AWSCLIV2.msi, I don't see any registry entries. (That's a real shame.  Nothing like a Version=X.X.X to really help make this problem easier.)

I see a bunch of files getting installed to [ProgramFiles64Folder]\Amazon\AWSCLIV2 although the user does have the option to change this in the UI.

The UpgradeCode is {E1C1971C-384E-4D6D-8D02-F1AC48281CF8}.  Let's start here.

Take a look at the concept of variables and InstallConditions on these pages:

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_define_searches.html

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/productsearch.html

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html

That should give you enough information to get the rest of the way there.

Comment: Since they dont have any entry in registry it difficult to track but if we want to do Filesearch based on  the installation directory is not default to ProgramFiles, user has choice to change  the installation path.

Comment: You want to do a ProductSearch.

Comment: Yes I want to do AWSLI x.x.x. the version installed or not machine .